# How to retrieve a range of ordered data from DB in case a new insertion changed that order?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, web-services

I am implementing an webservice API which retrieves the posts (post_id, posted_date, content,view_count) from Database.

```
posts?start=0&&per_page=5
```

This will get the top 5 posts ordered by view_count, then if user moves down or clicks next page, we will retrieve the next 5 posts by sending

`posts?start=5&&per_page=5`

But what if we get new post inserted in the table bwtween the two queries? in this case we may found a previously returned post being returned again.

For example:

```
post_id | posted date   | content | view_count
1           20160301        test1       100
2           20160302        test2       90
3           20160303        test3       80
4           20160304        test4       70
5           20160305        test4       60

6           20160306100     test6       50
....
```

then after the first query but before the second query, the view_count of post_id=6 increased to 65, then the table become(after ordering by view_count):

```
post_id | posted_date   | content | view_count
1           20160301        test1       100
2           20160302        test2       90
3           20160303        test3       80
4           20160304        test4       70
6           20160306        test6       65

5           20160305        test5       60      (previously returned)
....
```

In this case what should I do to filter the previously returned values and return next 5 posts? Is this possible in MYSQL?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid this kind of behaviour?

Comment: @Oleg Komarov, maybe my previous ask is not so clear, please check it again.
The reason is that I don't want to display previously returned posts, user will feel strange and annoyed.

Comment: Database State will change in a multi-user system. You can't rely on the order of something that is changing after the user requests it. Either live with it or run your query in whatever MySQL has that is similar to SQL server's read committed snapshot isolation or oracle's standard read committed mode. You won't get the latest data, of course, if you do it that way.

Comment: @NWest, do you think it would be a good idea to create a table post_view which only stores the post_id and view_count and make it more stable, for example update that table each 10 minutes? in this case we read post_view which won't change all the time.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Cursor based pagination,if you use increment as your table id  you can use it as the following

```
select * from posts where id > {id} limit 10
```

where you pass the last item id in your request 
posts?startIndex={id}&&per_page=10

Comment: yes, this is a good solution if I want to retrieve the posts ordered by posted_date (post_id is AUTO_INCREMENT), but in case I want to retrieve the posts ordered by view_count, what would be the solution?